# Why does anchor tag affect multiple lines

Tags: html, href

I'm new in HTML and I wrote this some code:

```html
<div id = "here">
    <a href="#end">
    <p>stay here</p>
</div>
 
<button id="test" onclick="clickSpecialButton('click')">click</button>
<span onmouseover="clickSpecialButton('hover')">hover</span>
<div id="start"></div>
<h1>My first web page</h1>
<figure>
    <img src="globe_kyw.jpg" width=90 height=90>
    <figcaption>Tixall Obelisk</figcaption>
</figure>
<nav id="main_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/reference/">Reference</a></li>
        <li><a href="/articles/">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="end">
    text
</div>
```

The result is the text in it: ("stay here", "hover", "My first web page", "Tixall Obelisk") all of it underline and it link to `#end`.

I wanted only what inside the div with `id = "here"` to be linked to `#end`.

What's wrong with what I did?

Comment: You're just missing the closing `</a>` tag after `<p>stay here</p>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `a` tag, try closing it after the `p` tag like this:

```html
  <div id = "here">
   <a href="#end">
       <p>stay here</p>
   </a> <!-- Notice the close tag here -->
</div>
 
        <button id="test" onclick="clickSpecialButton('click')">click</button>
 <span onmouseover="clickSpecialButton('hover')">hover</span>
 <div id="start"></div>
 <h1>My first web page</h1>
 <figure>
  <img src="globe_kyw.jpg" width=90 height=90>
  <figcaption>Tixall Obelisk</figcaption>
 </figure>
 <nav id="main_nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>
   <li><a href="/reference/">Reference</a></li>
   <li><a href="/articles/">Articles</a></li>
   <li><a href="/about/">About us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div id="end">
  text
 </div>
```